# how to get key of an array by using object in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one is like-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 2
            [attendance_type] => leave
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_id] => 3
            [attendance_type] => absent
        )

)
```

and other one is -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [attendance_id] => 4
            [student_id] => 2
        )

)
```

From the first array I need to take `attendance_type` with correspond `student_id`, so I'm trying to pick key from the array first then `attendacnce_type`. How it possible??

Comment: try using array_keys() function. (http://php.net/array_keys)

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: You have to loop into arrays and compare the desired key

Comment: @AlivetoDie I student_id from the second array and I want to pick attendance_type from the first array with respond with student_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$arrayFirst = [['student_id' => 2, 'attendance_type' => 'leave'], ['student_id' => 3, 'attendance_type' => 'absent']];
$arraySecond = ['attendance_id' => 4, 'student_id' => 2];

foreach ($arrayFirst as $key => $arrayFst) {
    if($arraySecond['student_id'] == $arrayFst['student_id']) {
        $firstArrayKeyValue = $key;
        $attendance_type  = $arrayFst['attendance_type'];
    }
}
echo $firstArrayKeyValue."<br>".$attendance_type;

?>
```